# How to get search results sorted by language in solr?

Tags: search

We have used [Apache solr multilingual](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr_multilingual) module for language specific search.
But we want the other language results to be shown below the current language search result.
How we can achieve it using solr?

Is there any module needed or any custom coding require?

Below is the example for displaying search results :-

> If I am currently using site in german and searched for any content
>   then german results needs to be appear first and then other language
>   content.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build your search with the apachesolr_views module (https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr_views), allow all languages and then group by language in the view.